# trying to instantiate the record in a model for CRUD operations in Django getting error "update_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'eid'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, crud

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class angelaFormModel(models.Model):
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    confirm_email=models.EmailField(unique= True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    confirm_password=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.First_name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import angelaFormModel
from django import forms

class angelaFormModel_form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = angelaFormModel
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'confirm_password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = '__all__'

class angelaFormModelUpdate_form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = angelaFormModel
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'confirm_password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = ['First_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'password', 'confirm_password']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import angelaFormModel_form, angelaFormModelUpdate_form
from .models import angelaFormModel

# working
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

# working
def create(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': angelaFormModel_form, 'message': 'Please, fill the form carefully...'})

    else:
        form = angelaFormModel_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            confirm_email = form.cleaned_data.get('confirm_email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            confirm_password = form.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

            if email != confirm_email:
                return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': angelaFormModel_form,
                                                       'message': 'Please, fill the form again! Provided email is not matching'})

            if password != confirm_password:
                return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': angelaFormModel_form,
                                                       'message': 'Please, fill the form again!, Provided password is not matching'})

            form.save()
            return render(request, 'create.html',{'form': angelaFormModel_form,
                                                  'message': 'Bingo! your form hase been submitted.'})

    # return render(request, 'create.html')
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': angelaFormModel_form, 'message': 'Please, fill the form again with '
                                                                                    'another email. Provided email '
                                                                                    'already exists.'})

# working
def update(request):
    return render(request, 'update.html')

# not working
def update_user(request, eid):
    obj = angelaFormModel.objects.get(email= eid)
    form = angelaFormModel_form(request.POST, instance= obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("home")
    return render(request, 'update_user.html', {'form': form})

# working
def delete(request):
    return render(request, 'delete.html')

# working
def deleted(request):
    email_ID = request.POST.get('email_id')
    print(email_ID)
    angelaFormModel.objects.filter(email= email_ID).delete()
    return render(request, 'deleted.html')

#working
def retrieve(request):
    return render(request, 'retrieve.html')

# working
def retrieve_detail(request):
    emailID = request.POST.get('email_id')
    context = angelaFormModel.objects.get(email = emailID)
    return render(request, 'retrieve_detail.html', {'detail': context})

# working
def list(request):
    context = {}
    context['dataset'] = angelaFormModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

**templates**

**update.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>update</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>update</h1>

<h3>Please, Provide the email id of the user to update the user's data.</h3>

<!--<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_user' %}">-->
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update_user' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Email: <input type="email" name="eid">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**update_user.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>update_user</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>update_user</h1>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    First Name: {{ form.First_name }}<br><br>
    Last Name: {{ form.last_name }}<br><br>
    Contact No: {{ form.phone }}<br><br>
    Password: {{ form.password }}<br><br>
    Confirm Password: {{ form.confirm_password }}<br><br>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Error log:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
E:\Development3\django\maneesh2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
E:\Development3\django\maneesh2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
```

and also please explain the concept of instantiation of record in a model and how to use it to perform UPADET in crud operations in Django. I am stuck here and not able to perform the UPDATE operation and it is very frustrating and I have tried everything and searched online for a solution. Please help with this I am a beginner and have just started to learn the Django.

Answer (score 1):

hym what is email id? it is email field? if you want to do it like this it should be:

```
    def update_user(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            eid = request.POST.get('eid','')
            try:
                obj = angelaFormModel.objects.get(email= eid)
            except ObjectDoesNotExists:
                return redirect("home")
            form = angelaFormModel_form(request.POST, instance= obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect("home")
            else:
                form = angelaFormModel_form( instance= obj)
                return render(request, 'update_user.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            print('you shouldnt be here')
            return redirect("home")
```

so you want at update.html provide email address and on that base edit AngelaFormModel?

Its still wrong way to do this... you should provide id of angelaformmodel as kwarg.
in template link:

```
{% url 'update_user' id %}
```

in urls.py:

```
path('update_user/<int:id>' views.update_user, name='update_user')
```

and in view:

```
def update_user(request, id):
    obj = angelaFormModel.objects.get(id= id)
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = angelaFormModel_form(request.POST, instance= obj)
         # rest
    else:
        form = angelaFormModel_form( instance= obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, Waldemar. I am able to create an instance but the form is not getting validated... could you please help me with that too... and if possible could you please explain what is happening...

Comment: again, thanks it is working now... in my user_update.html  I removed all {{form.field}} values and just added {{ form }}... but don't exactly know how it is working...

Comment: its django :) it makes tons of stuff for you. You need to dig in documantation of modelForm